# WiFi problems: com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[1552]: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0

Tags: network

Yeah, I'm having a lot of WiFi reliability issues and am seeing this log message, which I can't google either

com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[1552]: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0.

The WiFi works in the location where I see this but often is extremely unreliable (connection drops suddenly), while in the same place, my Android phone connects fine.

Since it's only a specific location, it might be that the Mac OS is kind of sensitive to a router problem. But it would be nice to get rid off.

Any ideas?

I'm on a Macbook Pro '15 2011 with El Capitan.

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same problems with both a MacBook Air and a MacBook Pro.

Disabling and re-eanbling the Wifi on the computer fixes the issue temporarily.

iPad and iPhone are able to connect without any problems.